# ¿como dibujar un cuadrado con * en js?

Tags: javascript

Hola soy nuevo en la programación con JavaScript, me tope con un ejercicio que pide hacer un cuadrado usando asteriscos, con funciones donde se ingrese el alto y el ancho que se quiera y lo muestres en la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debe quedar algo así,este es el condigo con el que e estado probando pero hasta el momento no e logrado hacer el espacio en el centro

```js
function rectangulo(alto,ancho){
    console.log("*".repeat(ancho))
    for (i=0; i<alto-2;i++){
        console.log("*"+" ".repeat(ancho-2)+"*")
    }
    console.log("*".repeat(ancho))
}
rectangulo(4,6);
```

Comment: Eso es un rectangulo... quiero decir... si tomamos los asteriscos como unidades, tienes 5u de ancho por 4u de alto... aunque si le pones 5u de alto aún parecerá más un rectangulo, je

Comment: Supongo que lo querrán de otra forma, pero esto lo hace en la consola: `console.log('\n*****\n*   *\n*   *\n*****\n')`

Comment: ahh ok, si me falto especificar mas, es para hacer con una función que se le ingrese el alto y el ancho que se quiera

Comment: Pues ya te he dado las pistas que necesitas para hacerlo, usando `console.log` y forzando el salto de línea con `\n`.  Si a partir de aquí no se te ocurre nada entonces mejor que repases lo aprendido.  El problema de tu pregunta es que no muestras lo que has intentado ni el error que tienes, y aquí no hacemos tareas, lo siento. Repasa [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento básico de este sitio, gracias.

Comment: buenas tardes, ¿Qué haz intentado hacer?

Comment: ook gracias, tengo que ver la guía de como funciona esto, perdón por dejar a mochas al principio

Comment: Si quieres formar un cuadrado, no creo que sea necesario recibir 2 parámetros para definir el ancho y alto, ya que si fuese así, sería un rectángulo. Un cuadrado tiene sus lados iguales, de la cual recibiría 1 parámetro tu función. Confirmar si lo que quieres es un cuadrado o un rectángulo, las soluciones serían distintas.

Comment: ok,lo e logrado después de investigar y leer los comentario, y si si seria un rectángulo xd, gracias por los comentarios

Comment: En lugar de colocarlo en la pregunta, ponlo en una respuesta, así la comunidad lo verá mejor, sino no se entiende la pregunta, gracias (y revierte la pregunta a su estado anterior editandola)

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto mi solución, para ambos casos (cuadrado o rectángulo), podrías utilizar 3 **`for`** para dibujar la estructura de la figura, el primer **`for`** lo que hace es dibujar la primera línea horizontal del dibujo, el segundo **`for`** sería lo que está entre la primera línea horizontal  y última línea horizontal, y el último **`for`**, la última línea horizontal. Todo esto va a ir dependiendo del parámetro que reciba tu función (en este caso, el ancho y el alto de la figura, o solo el tamaño de los lados) por ejemplo:

```js
* * * * * * * // el primer for dibuja esta línea
*           * // 
*           * // el segundo for, estas 3 líneas del medio
*           * //
* * * * * * * // el tercer for, dibuja esta línea
```

---

##### Solución para dibujar un cuadrado:

```js
function dibujarCuadrado(lados) {
    let result = '';
  
    // linea de arriba
    for (let i = 0; i < lados; i++) {
      result += '* ';
    }
    
    result += '\n';
  
    // cuerpo del cuadrado
    for (let i = 0; i < lados - 2; i++) {
      result += '*';
      for (let j = 0; j < lados + lados - 3; j++) {
        result += ' ';
      }
      result += '*\n';
    }
  
    // linea de abajo
    for (let i = 0; i < lados; i++) {
      result += '* ';
    }
    
    return result;
  }
  
console.log(dibujarCuadrado(3));
console.log(dibujarCuadrado(5));
console.log(dibujarCuadrado(7));
console.log(dibujarCuadrado(9));
```

---

##### Solución para dibujar un rectángulo:

```js
function dibujarRectangulo(ancho, alto) {
  let result = '';

  // linea de arriba
  for (let i = 0; i < ancho; i++) {
    result += '* ';
  }

  result += '\n';

  // cuerpo del rectangulo
  for (i = 0; i < alto - 2; i++) {
    result += '*' + ' '.repeat(ancho * 2 - 3) + '*\n';
  }

  // linea de abajo
  for (let i = 0; i < ancho; i++) {
    result += '* ';
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(dibujarRectangulo(3, 3));
console.log(dibujarRectangulo(5, 4));
console.log(dibujarRectangulo(7, 5));
console.log(dibujarRectangulo(9, 6));
```